# Detect ionic/angular modal size (breakpoint) change?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, position

I have an Ionic 6 / angular 13 project which I am working with some modals. My modals have multiple breakpoints and they contains a card with header and content and also two buttons. I want these buttons to be visible at any breakpoints but always be at the bottom of the page view.

modal config:

```js
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: MyComponent,
  backdropBreakpoint: 0.1,
  initialBreakpoint: 0.5,
  breakpoints: [smallestBreakPoint, 0.5, 0.9]
})
```

`MyComponent` template:

```html
<ion-card style="background-color: white; height: 90%;">
  <ion-card-header class="pb-0 pt-2">
    <ion-card-title>
      ...
    </ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-item lines="none">
      ...
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item lines="none" (click)="..." button>
      ...
    </ion-item>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="text-center">
        <ion-button expand="block" class="custom-button" color="light">
          ...
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class="text-center" size="8">
        <ion-button expand="block" class="custom-button" (click)="...">
          ...
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

I tried changing `<ion-row>` and `<ion-card>` position and offset to everything, and none of them did the trick. Also I tried `<ion-footer>`. Please note that the card div is larger than it should be because it should open fully on 0.9 breakpoint.

Expected output:

[image]

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using ion footer? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/footer#usage

Comment: Yes. didn't work either.

Comment: did u try to give the row that contains the buttons a css position: fixed and bottom:0?

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this snippet it's working fine for me:

```
<ion-modal
#modal
trigger="open-modal"
(willDismiss)="onWillDismiss($event)"
[initialBreakpoint]="0.5"
[breakpoints]="[0, 1]"
handleBehavior="cycle"
id="open-modal"
>
<ng-template class="block">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons>
        ...
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-card style="background-color: white;">
<ion-card-header class="pb-0 pt-2">
<ion-card-title>
  ...
</ion-card-title>
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content>
<ion-item lines="none">
  ...
</ion-item>
<ion-item lines="none" (click)="..." button>
  ...
</ion-item>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col class="text-center">
    <ion-button expand="block" class="custom-button" color="light">
      ...
    </ion-button>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="text-center" size="8">
    <ion-button expand="block" class="custom-button" (click)="...">
      ...
    </ion-button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
</ng-template>
</ion-modal>
```

and the TS file should import:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { IonModal } from '@ionic/angular';
```

and these are some of useful functions if you'd like:

```
//inside your class
@ViewChild(IonModal)
modal!: IonModal;
cancel() {
this.modal.dismiss();
}

async openModal() {
return await this.modal.present();
}
```